# Cannot install plugin or updates in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, plugins

I have a server set with NGINX: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

```
Recipe
Abridged basic setup
```

I have deployed WP in this directory: `/var/www/blog.example.com/`

`/var/www` and `/var/www/blog.example.com/` does have nginx:nginx file/dir perms.

```
wp-config.php - 644
wp-content - 755
wp-content/plugins - 755
```

NGINX is running as `nginx` user.

I can browse in entire WordPress site including admin. However, when I want to install a new plugin or update I got always the message:

> Installing plugin: iThemes Security (before Better WP Security) 7.9.1
>
> Downloading the installation package from
> [https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/better-wp-security.7.9.1.zip…](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/better-wp-security.7.9.1.zip%E2%80%A6)
>
> Decompressing…
>
> An error occurred while installing iThemes Security: Directory could not be created

What's I am wrong?

All libraries required according to https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/handbook/server-environment/ was installed.

When I try to upgrade a theme, for example, I got 200 code "OK" from a web server, but, I don't see anything in the error_log of NGINX.

Also, I've checked the php-fpm but I don't see any updating error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-fpm was running as an apache user.
I've switched the user into Nginx and It's solved. :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the issue is the 'plugins' folder writing permissions. WP downloads the zip archive of the plugin then it decompresses it to the 'plugins' folder.

This article will help:
https://secure.wphackedhelp.com/blog/fix-file-and-folder-permissions-error-wordpress/

Comment: Try to change the 'plugins' folder permission to 755.

Comment: It does have 755 perms in wp-content/{plugins,themes...}

Answer (score 0):

Just adding onto @sincorchetes answer, to those who need more specific instruction:

```
vim /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

I changed the lines

```
user = apache
group = apache
```

to

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

Then restarted the php-fpm and nginx service

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
systemctl restart nginx
```